# Does an assignment operation have a boolean value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Let's suppose I have an assignment operation:

```
x = f()
```

with f either returning None or an object.

Would it be possible to say:

```
if x = f():
    do_smth()
```

with the statement evaluating to True if an object is returned and False if None is returned?

Unfortunately I wasn't able to answer this question by asking google :/ If anybody has a reference that discusses this topic I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Starting form python 3.8 you can do `if x := f():` [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

Comment: @OlvinRoght: Parentheses not needed, `if x := f():` is fine. Note that it's not just "object vs. None", it uses standard truthiness evaluation. If you want to test for non-`None`ness not, you'd do `if (x := f()) is not None:` (parentheses needed there, as `:=` has super low precedence, so otherwise you'd be assigning the result of `f() is not None` to `x`).

Comment: @ShadowRangerm, I've removed them right before you posted your comment, but in my code I still prefer to add parentheses for "highlighting" assignment expression.

Comment: Good to know, never stumbled over the := operator in Python, thank you both, and @OlvinRoght thanks for the PEP

Comment: @L1nuS01 See also https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions